# InputScope type NumericPassword doesn't work in my case

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

When I try to use the InputScope type NumericPassword? it doesn't hide input date:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Here is my code:

```
   <ValidationControl:ValidationControl x:Name="txtPIN"  GotFocus="PinTextBox_GotFocus" Margin="0,0,45,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" ValidationContent="Please insert a valid id" LostFocus="PinBoxLostFocus" InputScope="NumericPassword" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="200"  MinWidth="220" MinHeight="80"  MaxLength="4" Foreground="Black" Background="#DEFFFFFF" ValidationRule="{StaticResource pinValidationRule}" TextChanged="txtPIN_TextChanged">
                    <ValidationControl:ValidationControl.ValidationSymbol>
                        <Image Source="/img.png" Height="40" Width="40" />
                    </ValidationControl:ValidationControl.ValidationSymbol>
                </ValidationControl:ValidationControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

It does work for me, what is that ValidationControl usercontrol? Try using a simple textbox control first and see if it works.